# Activity restarts on Finish()

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android

I have a login-activity which I only want to show on startup and if the user logs out. So when the user is in the loggedin activity and clicks on the back-button I want to close the app rather than go back to the login activity.

I have successfully overwritten the back button callback:

```
public override bool OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
{
    if (keyCode == Keycode.Back)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Close activity");
        return true;
    }

    return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
}
```

which stops the backbutton from going back to the previous activity. However, including `Finish();` before `return true` does make the login activity reappear :(

This is the code I use after login:

```
Intent activity = new Intent(this, typeof(WorkOrderActivity));
StartActivity(activity);
```

Have tried a couple of Intentflags and LaunchModes but cant get it to work. According to the logs only one activity is started after login.

Comment: have you considered the possiblity of an "invisible" splash activity (Theme: No display) which checks if the user is logged in and starts the appropriate activity? That would be a better approach, let me know if you need some

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the normal behaviour to show the previous `Activity` after `finish()`

The `finish()` method just close the Activity which call it

You can hide your login form and check the user login status on your `onResume()` login Activity (and finish it if he is logged)

Comment: This worked. Thought `Finish()` would quit the entire application.

Comment: Don't forget to check if you are just opening the application, because if you don't and the user is already logged at startup, the application will close immediately :p

Comment: I did `Finish` just after logging in instead. Similar to how @Mitesh suggested, but without the flags.

Answer (score 3):

Try this it works..

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, WorkOrderActivity.class);
mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(mIntent);

finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should clear stack when starting another activity from Login activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |      Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

And when user logout you can start LoginActivity.

Answer (score 0):

```
public override bool OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
{
    if (keyCode == Keycode.Back)
    {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }

    return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
}
```